# http callout `Client credentials are missing` by using Basic Auth

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, httprequest, httppost

I am trying to  get the access token by calling PayPal API,I Am getting `Client credentials are missing` response.

```
 public static HttpResponse  GetAccessToken() {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        //request.setHeader('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
        request.setBody('grant_type=client_credentials'); 
        String username = 'username';
        String password = 'password';
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'Basic' +
            EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        request.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            // Deserializes the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
            Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            // Cast the values in the 'animals' key as a list
            /*List<Object> animals = (List<Object>) results.get('animals');
System.debug('Received the following animals:');
for (Object animal: animals) {
System.debug(animal);
}*/
        }
        System.debug(response.getBody());
        return response;   
    }
```

**Response:**

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client credentials are missing"}
```

Can anyone please help me What is missing here. It's working in Postman client.

Comment: Instead of setting grant type in header, set it in the body: setBody('grant_type=client_credentials' );

Comment: request.setBody('grant_type=client_credentials'); Tried, still same response. Updated my code

Comment: try with grant type present at body and header both the places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code working fine, Not sure what's different between the above and below code.

```
 String username = 'username';
        String password = 'password';
        string endpoint = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token';
        string body = 'grant_type=client_credentials';
        
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' +  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        system.debug('Encoder Value' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue));
        http http = new http();
        httpRequest request = new httpRequest();
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        request.setBody(body);
        httpResponse Res = http.send(request);
```

Comment: The order of setting the Method/Endpoint/Header/Body is different, just a thought.

Comment: just for clarity username will be the client_id & the password will be client_secret in oAuth https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/client-credentials-flow